# Python dataframe running total based on a sort key

Tags: python, teradata

I like to get a running total per a sort key. I have checked most of the post for groupby functions. however, it still the problem for me to group them together by different level of sort key. can any expert helps me on this question!

Many thanks!!

Here I have a dataframe :

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrZSI.png)

| SORT KEY | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 4 |
| AA | 9 |
| AAA | 6 |
| AAAA | 2 |
| AAAAA | 56 |
| AAB | 6 |
| AABA | 2 |
| AABAA | 56 |
| AB | 9 |
| ABA | 6 |
| ABAA | 6 |
| ABAAA | 56 |

the expected result :

[expected running total output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOHyR.png)

| SORT KEY | Value | Running Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 4 |
| AA | 9 | 13 |
| AAA | 6 | 19 |
| AAAA | 2 | 21 |
| AAAAA | 56 | 77 |
| AAB | 6 | 19 |
| AABA | 2 | 21 |
| AABAA | 56 | 77 |
| AB | 9 | 13 |
| ABA | 6 | 19 |
| ABAA | 6 | 25 |
| ABAAA | 56 | 81 |

Comment: MySQL or Teradata? Based on which logic the running total resets?

Comment: Hi dnoeth, thanks for your reply! the output is from Teradata. I am fine to do the running total when doing the query on Teredata or handle it via Python. the reset is based on sort key. you could see here the sort key should be A (value : 5, Running Total : 5) > AA (value : 2, Running Total : 7)>AAA (value : 3, Running Total : 10). but there is an alternative AAB which should be (value : 5, running Total : 5+7 = 12). Hope it is clear!

Comment: That's real tricky. Does the sort key really look like your example A-AA-AAB, etc? Adding char by char?

Comment: @dnoeth, Yes. the sort key is in ascending order. the running total is adding up per the previous string.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a solution based on Windowed Aggregates, but this task seems to be a perfect match for recursion:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
 ( 
   SELECT sort_key, val, val AS running_total, 1 AS len
   FROM tab AS t
   -- start with a single charcater
   WHERE  Char_Length(t.sort_key) = 1

   UNION ALL
   -- do the running total
   SELECT t.sort_key, t.val, running_total + t.val, cte.len +1
   FROM tab AS t
   JOIN cte -- next key starts with the previous key and adds a char
     ON Substring(t.sort_key FROM 1 FOR len) = cte.sort_key
    AND Char_Length(t.sort_key) = len +1 
 ) 
SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY sort_key
```